# Intellij crashing after update

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, terminal, intellij-plugin

./idea.sh

```
CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:491)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:503)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.licel.b.Z@
    at fuck_the_regulations_v320.dH.<clinit>(dH.java)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.licel.b.Z@
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:246)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:592)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    ... 7 more
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message Outstanding error when calling method in invokeJavaAgentMainMethod at src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 619
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "success" with message invokeJavaAgentMainMethod failed at src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 459
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 422
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x8b650a]  jni_FatalError+0xba
V  [libjvm.so+0xa35e92]  JvmtiExport::post_vm_initialized()+0x132
V  [libjvm.so+0xe69d6b]  Threads::create_vm(JavaVMInitArgs*, bool*)+0x95b
V  [libjvm.so+0x8cff71]  JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x51
C  [libjli.so+0x3a1f]  JavaMain+0x8f
C  [libjli.so+0x7d79]  ThreadJavaMain+0x9

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGABRT (0x6) at pc=0x00007f62f635100b (sent by kill), pid=20704, tid=20721
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment JBR-17.0.9+7-1087.7-jcef (17.0.9+7) (build 17.0.9+7-b1087.7)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM JBR-17.0.9+7-1087.7-jcef (17.0.9+7-b1087.7, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x4300b]  gsignal+0xcb
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t 9223372036854775808 %h" (or dumping to /home/ja/Downloads/idea-IU-233.11799.300/bin/core.20704)
#
JNI global refs:
JNI global refs: 8, weak refs: 0

JNI global refs memory usage: 867, weak refs: 865

OOME stack traces (most recent first):
Classloader memory used:
Loader bootstrap                                                                       : 1247K
Loader com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader                                          : 45046B
Loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader                                 : 36590B
Loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader                            : 14119B
Loader jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader                                      : 434B

# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/ja/java_error_in_idea_20704.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/JBR
#
Aborted (core dumped)
`your text`
```

I downloaded new version of Intellij ultimate with the license and everything from their official website on my Linux Mint.I got .tar file, extracted  it and when i open terminal,the command ./idea.sh wont open the IDE..I always had this problem so i would just go and open it with sudo ./idea.sh command and everything worked.(Probably bad solution). I have been struggling with this problem for the past days. Above is what my console has to say when i run the IDE.And when i run it with sudo it opens but still crashes after 3 seconds.I should note that once i also had this problem when i installed some random plugin from marketplace after which IDE would crash after 3 seconds as well,so i used that time to quickly uninstall the plugin and after it everything worked normally.I suspect this has something to do with this ai assistant plugin or smth...

Comment: You stack trace has some questionable class names. Have you contacted JetBrains support? It's part of what you paid for, after all.

Comment: this isn't cracked version...i am using a version for students and teachers which is free ultimate version .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by deleting .config/JetBrains folder and running ide again and installation process started again.No more crashing :).I also had other Intellij an old cracked version which might have caused the issue(was also in the JetBrains folder)

Answer (score 3):

> fuck_the_regulations

Remove the crack agent you installed from the [.vmoptions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869) file.

Please use the licensed version or the free Community Edition.

Comment: I have a legal license with similar problem:
"CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true"

Comment: @WaldemarWosiński Either your problem is different, or you installed the crack agent for some reason. Anyway, contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new with the logs to get help.

Comment: CrazyCoder, test your website on Firefox as well please. Copy/paste is broken.

Comment: @WaldemarWosiński Please don't hijack comments/answers with totally unrelated problems, report site bugs to webmaster.